# sd-encrypt with keyfile on optional external partition

Tags: linux, encryption, systemd, luks

## Context

I have an encrypted /home partition, which can be unlocked with a passphrase and a keyfile. This keyfile is on a USB drive which I keep at home. This means that someone who steals my laptop from my bag while I'm travelling can't access my personal files, but that when I'm home I don't have to enter it. The rest of my system (`/`, `/boot`, etc) isn't encrypted. I am aware this could be a security risk but that's not my concern.

## Things that work as expected

Booting with the USB attached correctly decrypts and mounts /home.
Booting "Boot with passphrase" correctly decrypts and mounts /home after I entered the passphrase (both with or without the USB attached).

## Things that don't work as expected

If I boot the first option "Boot with USB or passphrase" without the USB attached, I get the following errors after 1m30s (!):

```
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/<USB_UUID>.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /run/systemd/cryptsetup/keydev-encHome.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for encHome.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
```

and after waiting 1m30s (!) for the second job to time out:

```
systemd[1]: dev-mapper-encHome.device: Job dev-mapper-encHome.device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/encHome.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/encHome.
```

I say 1m30s (!) with an exclamation mark because I have `rd.luks.options=timeout=16,keyfile-timeout=16` and `rootflags=x-systemd.device-timeout=16` set in my kernel parameters, so I'd expect these to last 16s at most. I'm also surprised that the `File System Check` dependency failed, even though I have `fsck.mode=skip` set.

After the second failure, I don't get any prompt to enter my passphrases, but get dumped directly inside an emergency shell.

### How I expected things to work

I want systemd to wait 16 seconds for my USB to come online and decrypt /home directly if it does. If it doesn't, I want it to ask me for the passphrase and decrypt my /home with that.

## Configuration

### /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

```
MODULES=()
HOOKS="base systemd autodetect modconf block keyboard sd-vconsole sd-encrypt filesystems fsck"
```

### /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/encHome  /home  ext4  defaults  0  2
```

(the USB with the keyfile is not in here)

### /etc/crypttab

empty

### /etc/defaults/cryptsetup

non-existent

### /boot/refind_linux.conf

```
"Boot with USB or passphrase"
    "ro root=UUID=<ROOT_UUID>
    apparmor=1 security=apparmor
    resume=UUID=<SWAP_UUID>
    initrd=/boot/intel-ucode.img initrd=/boot/initramfs-%v.img
    rd.luks.name=<CRYPT_UUID>=encHome
    rd.luks.key=<CRYPT_UUID>=/keyfile:UUID=<USB_UUID>
    rd.luks.options=timeout=16,keyfile-timeout=16
    rootflags=x-systemd.device-timeout=16
    fsck.mode=skip"

"Boot with passphrase"
    "ro root=UUID=<ROOT_UUID>
    apparmor=1 security=apparmor
    resume=UUID=<SWAP_UUID>
    initrd=/boot/intel-ucode.img initrd=/boot/initramfs-%v.img
    rd.luks.name=<CRYPT_UUID>=encHome"
```

(the actual file doesn't have newlines but for the sake of readability I've added them)

### `lsblk -o name,fstype,uuid`

```
NAME        FSTYPE      UUID
sda                     
├─sda2      swap        <SWAP_UUID>
├─sda4      crypto_LUKS <CRYPT_UUID>
│ └─encHome ext4
└─sda6      ext4        <ROOT_UUID>
sdb                     
└─sdb1      ext4        <USB_UUID>
```

(and several other irrelevant partitions)

### `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda4`

```
UUID: <CRYPT_UUID>
Key Slot 0: ENABLED  ( the passphrase )
Key Slot 1: ENABLED  ( the keyfile )
```

### systemd services

`systemd-fsck-root.service` is `enabled-runtime`

`systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-encHome.service` is `static` and `active` on keyfile boot (with USB attached).

#### versions

```
uname -r
    5.5.2-1-MANJARO

core/systemd 242.153-3
core/cryptsetup 2.3.0-1.1
extra/refind-efi 0.11.3-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently nothing was wrong with the config files, but since I've updated to

```
5.5.8-1-MANJARO
systemd 244.3-2
```

it works exactly as expected.